# Convert a vector<dlib::point> to an NSArray so it can be passed to a Swift class

Tags: c++, objective-c, nsarray

I'm using dlib's facial landmark detector and want to store the facial landmark coordinates in an array that can be used in Swift.

At the minute I've stored the landmark coordinates in a vector:

```
std::vector<dlib::point> facialLandmarks;
```

---

```
for (unsigned long k = 0; k < shape.num_parts(); k++) {
            dlib::point p = shape.part(k);

            facialLandmarks.push_back(p);
        }
```

I now want to write a function that will convert the vector into an NSArray so that I can return the array and use it within my Swift code.

When I try things like the following:

```
 NSArray* facialLandmarksArray = &facialLandmarks[0];
```

I get an error:

```
Cannot initialize a variable of type 'NSArray *__strong' with an rvalue of type 'std::__1::__vector_base<dlib::vector<long, 2>, std::__1::allocator<dlib::vector<long, 2> > >::value_type *' (aka 'dlib::vector<long, 2> *')
```

I really know very little about Objective-C or C++ but need to use it for Dlib. Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: I don't know Swift, but looking at the docs, how did you determine that you need an `NSArray` as opposed to an `Array`?

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf that piece of code is actually Obj-C, there's no Swift code in the question. `Array` is a Swift type, Obj-C only has `NSArray`.

Comment: @DávidPásztor: Thanks.

Comment: I have created a bridging header so that I can use an Objective-C class (DlibWrapper.mm) with the rest of my Swift code. It has worked well but now I don't know how to store the facial landmark coordinates in a data structure that can be passed to one of my Swift classes.

Comment: @Hardy143 Does the answer below work for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NSArray`s can only contain *Objective-C* objects, no *C++* objects. So you have to convert your points to `NSValue`s first. Something like this should work:

```
NSMutableArray* facialLandmarksArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity: facialLandmarks.size()];

for (auto const& pt: facialLandmarks) {
    [facialLandmarksArray addObject: [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(pt.x, pt.y)]];
}
```

And make sure this is compiled as *Objective-C++* (file ending *.mm).

However, note that this does not scale well for large vectors. *Swift* and *C++* are both able to make sure that the values of such arrays/vectors are stored in [consecutive memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality_of_reference), bridging through *Objective-C* destroys this locality.

Comment: With this approach each point is copied twice: when building `facialLandmarks` vector from shape parts and when building `facialLandmarksArray` from `facialLandmarks`.  This can be reduced to one copy by eliminating the `facialLandmarks` vector and populating the `facialLandmarksArray` directly from the shape parts.

Comment: Another observation: `dlib::point` is a `typedef` for `vector<long,2>`, so `pt.x` and `pt.y` won't work.  I'm looking at http://dlib.net/linear_algebra.html#point; is that the correct library?  Well, the error message also suggests that `point` is that `typedef`.

Comment: @Tobi thanks so much for your answer. It seems to have worked fine. One thing however is when loop through the array in Swift and print the value it prints as NSPoint: {297, 238}. Is it possible to print it without the NSPoint text? I want to write this data to a txt file.

Comment: @Hardy143 I know about bridging between *C++* and *Objective-C*, but not so much about the *Swift* part... Maybe you can formulate that as a new question and let the *Swift* community answer the printing stuff.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of the challenges here are:

1) We want to minimize copying of the landmark points, since such copying will affect software performance and memory footprint.

2) How do we use C++ `vector`'s members, instances of type `dlib::point` in this case, in Swift code?

Addressing these challenges depends on the use case.  Some questions to consider:

1) How important is performance/memory footprint?  If this is not an issue, copying the values when making them available to Swift is OK.  Of course, this also depends on whether C++ code has to use values changed by Swift.

2) How many landmark points are we talking about?  If it's a hundred points or so, then copying them is unlikely to be a performance hit.

3) Is Swift code just going to use the values of the landmark points returned by the C++ library, or is it going to modify those values and expect C++ code to "see" those changes?

4) How many times, typically, will Swift code access each of the landmark points?  If each point is accessed multiple times, then it's better to copy all the points once into a structure that can be used in Swift without creating a copy on each access rather than making a copy of a coordinate each time Swift accesses it.

5) How much complexity can be tolerated?  Are you willing to write a lot of C++ code?  Are you comfortable working with pointer types in Swift, e.g. `UnsafeMutablePointer`?

And here are some ideas on how to do this:

1) Construct, in Objective-C++, a collection that can be used in Swift and copy landmark point coordinate values into that structure.  @Tobi's answer is an example.

2) Similar to (1) above, but the Swift-accessible collection contains pointers to coordinate values.

3) Write an Objective-C++ class whose interface is accessible from Swift and all C++-specific code is hidded in the implementation.  The interface could allow Swift code to read (and write, if needed), specific coordinates of specific landmark points.

4) A variation of (3) where Swift code accesses pointers to the coordinate values.  Care would be needed when using these on the Swift side to avoid copying of the coordinate values.

If you provide some specifics about your use case, I can try to come up with an example.